# Сколько уровней приоритетов потоков исполнения в MacOS?

Tags: linux, windows, многопоточность, macos

Сейчас занимаюсь освоением многопоточности (в *Java*), нашел информацию о том, что в *Windows* только 7 уровней приоритетов, в *JVM* их 10, а в виртуальной машине Oracle для *Linux* их вообще нет (они игнорируются).

НО, так как я полностью стал яблочником, мне стало интересно: сколько же возможных уровней приоритетов в ***MacOS***? И зависят ли они как-то от версии ОС? В Гугле информацию об этом пока не нашел:(

P.s. вообще приоритетностью пользоваться не рекомендуется по описаным выше причинам (отличия в кол-ве уровней приоритетов в каждой ОС, а приоритеты потоков зависят от платформы, что не своейственно для Java), но этот вопрос не дает мне покоя!!)

Comment: Непонятно, откуда вы взяли информацию про «в Linux их вообще нет», если в линуксе есть 41 приоритет

Comment: Ошибся, имелось ввиду, что в виртуальной машине Oracle для Linux их нет (точнее они игнорируются)

Comment: Собственно, [в macOS тоже 41 приоритет](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setpriority.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/setpriority) (и во FreeBSD тоже, раз уж на то пошло)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Хотя с другой стороны меня смущает фраза «For PRIO_DARWIN_THREAD, prio is either 0 (to remove current thread from background status) or PRIO_DARWIN_BG (to set current thread into background state)» — похоже, в macOS всё не так просто как в других юниксах

Comment: Странно, было бы логично предположить, что потоку, который имеет фоновое состояние, соответсвует наименьший приоритет, но исходя из формулировки на сайте Apple, поток с приоритетом 0 и поток, который находится в фоновом состоянии - это не одно и то же.